# How to create map Pick up Location input in Frontend. Magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, input, map

I want to create a *pick up input type* in frontend where the user will select the location in map n then I'll get *Latitude* and *Amplitude*.

[image]

Like you can see from the image. How can I create this? thanks

Comment: Where do you want to create this input field? Are you using a API to get the location?

Comment: I want to create this in my custom phtml form.. I'm currently stuck n dont know how to set this sort of input where customer will add his location by map n I'll get his Amplitude n Latitude